# Attribute error while reading and writing an excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Since many days I have gone loads of resources but not able to find the solution.
I want to make data into some relevant form to create visualizations in tableau. Data is present in excel file so I am using openpyxl engine to read the excel file

```
import pandas as pd

worksheet_data = pd.read_excel("Downloads\\Data-file-Europe-Power-Sector-2020.xlsx",engine= 
'openpyxl', sheet_name = 'Data', usecols = "A,B,C,D")
 worksheet_data.head()
```

But I am getting following error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in 
__call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

   ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in 
_repr_html_(self)
    732         GH3541, GH3573
    733         """
--> 734         width, height = console.get_console_size()
    735         max_columns = get_option("display.max_columns")
    736         nb_columns = len(self.columns)

 ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in 
to_html(self, buf, encoding, classes, notebook, border)
    980             Buffer to write to. If None, the output is returned as a string.
    981         encoding : str, default “utf-8”
--> 982             Set character encoding.
    983         classes : str or list-like
    984             classes to include in the `class` attribute of the opening

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\html.py in 
__init__(self, formatter, classes, border, table_id, render_links)
     54         self.col_space = {
     55             column: f"{value}px" if isinstance(value, int) else value
---> 56             for column, value in self.fmt.col_space.items()
     57         }
     58 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The attribute error is also coming at the time of writing excel file. Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your dataset available online somewhere? Could you give a link to it?

Comment: I ran your code on my system on the first dataset link that I got. It ran without any errors on my python 3.6 with pandas 1.1.5 and openpyxl 3.0.7. [here](https://filebin.net/04tp64eq9w5so9dt) is the csv output of your query.